# how i change any image width and height values without stretching or cropping it

Tags: html, css, layout

I have an image . i want to make it a body background image  but the image is stretched all the solutions i found so far on internet to resolve this problem and maintain aspect ratio lead to cropping image and this is what happen when setting (bg-size : cover) the image aspect ratio is maintained and it fill the page but the image is cropped
so Q here is how i change any image width and height values without stretching or cropping it .......
first one is original , second is stretched third image is cropped

[image: original image]

[image: stretched image]

[image: stretched isue is solved but image is cropped]

Comment: first one is original , second is stretched third image is cropped

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking for is impossible - for the image to cover the entire screen/window without cropping or stretching, it would have to have the exact same dimensions as the screen/window.